# Add image to Checkbox in winforms

Tags: winforms, image, checkbox

I have a Image path(some thing like this "http://ABC/XYZ/PQR.gif").And I want to assign this image to checkbox in winforms using C#.winfroms checkbox does not have SRC,How can I assign this image to checkbox.?

Answer (score 1):

The *Background* of a check box can be *filled* with a provided image.

See

- [CheckBox Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743611(VS.85).aspx)
- [CheckBox Members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox_members.aspx)
- [Control.BackgroundImage Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.backgroundimage.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1. Set the BackGroundImage Property.
2. Change the BackGroundImageLayout
   Property to stretch.
3. Change the Font Color if required